# Using logical operators in querySelector CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to select all table cells that have `colSpan` or `rowSpan` bigger than 1. I know that you can do `querySelectorAll('td[colspan="3"]')` to select cells that meet a narrower condition.

But I need something like `querySelectorAll('td[colspan>"1"]')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to put conditional operator inside the `querySelector`. In your case, if you want to achieve it using only CSS selector then you can ignore the particular `colspan` condition and select the remaining using `:not` operator.

```
 td[colspan]:not(td[colspan = "1"]) {
   background : red;
 }
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td[colspan]:not(td[colspan = "1"]) {
background : red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this link : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-all-elements-by-data-attribute#get-all-dom-elements-by-partial-match-of-a-data-attribute

you can get elements with data-attribute starts with, ends with or contains with something like below:

```
// ✅ Get all where value of data-id starts with `bo`
const elements1 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id^="bo"]');
console.log(elements1); // ️ [div, div]

// ✅ Get all where value of data-id ends with `ox1`
const elements2 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id$="ox1"]');
console.log(elements2); // ️ [div]

// ✅ Get all where value of data-id contains with `box`
const elements3 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id*="box"]');
console.log(elements3); // ️ [div, div]
```

in your case you can do something like that:

```
const getAllTdColspanBiggerThanOne= (a) => {
    for (let i in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      if (a[i].getAttribute('colspan') > 1) {
        alert(a[i].getAttribute('colspan'));
      }
    }
}

const td = document.querySelectorAll("td[colspan]") // or document.querySelectorAll("[colspan]")

const tdColspanBiggerThanOne = getAllTdColspanBiggerThanOne(td)
```